# "Comment Field Is Required Error" when Submitting Comment Form ExpressionEngine

Tags: forms, comments

A very quick question, I'm trying to make a comment form but I get an error on submit that the Comment field is required, even though its filled in.

No Idea why as I checked other questions etc code seems fine.

```
      <div class="comment-form">
            <h3> Leave a comment </h3>
            {exp:comment:form channel="blog_post"}
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label>YOUR NAME<span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="{name}" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>YOUR EMAIL<span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" value="{email}" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>YOUR WEBSITE</label>
                        <input type="text" name="url" value="{url}" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>YOUR COMMENT<span>*</span></label>
                        <textarea name="comment">{comment}</textarea>

                    </li>
                    <li class="submit"><button type="submit">POST COMMENT</button></li>
                </ol>
            {/exp:comment:form}
        </div>
```

Can you spot an error? Or maybe direct me the right direction?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need an entry id to link the comment to.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to either specify an entry URL title or an entry ID

```
{exp:comment:form channel="blog_post" url__title = "{segment_x}"}
```